# How can I send SMS from Android to Azure IoT Hub

Tags: android, azure, sms, iot, azure-iot-hub

I am building a POC that uses an unlocked cellphone with only SMS capability to send GPS info to a central server. I'd like to use Azure's IoT hub, but I have searched and have not found any info on if you can send SMS INTO IoT hub or how.

Answer (score 2):

Use a Logic App triggered by a [Twilio SMS number](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-create-api-twilio). You then grab the SMS content and send it to IoT Hub. I believe there's a connector for that as well.

```
    Send SMS
        |
    Twilio triggered Logic App      \
        |                            |
    Get SMS body                     |  Logic App
        |                            |
    Place message into IoT Hub      /
```

If there's no IoT Hub connector then call an Azure Function and use that to send to IoT Hub.

Comment: OK, I'll try this and report back.